# How can I transition between two RGB colours in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, rgb, p5.js

## Coded snippet: Putting the question into context

Below, I have coded a little snippet using the p5.js library where a slider controls the number of bars that appear on a canvas. The colour of each bar is determined by multiplying the number of the bar that is being coloured by 255 / (the total number of bars - 1), so, **regardless of the number of bars, the first will always be black and the last will always be slightly off-white (with greyscale in between).**

Quick note: The last is off-white so I can see it against a white background.

Run the snippet here:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(200,200);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  numberOfBars = document.getElementById("barSlider").value;
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfBars; i++) {
    noStroke();
    var spaceInterval = width / numberOfBars;
    fill(i*(240/(numberOfBars-1)))
    rect(i * spaceInterval, 0, spaceInterval, (i + 1)  * spaceInterval);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.16/p5.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="range" min="2" max="100" value="10" id="barSlider">
  </body>
 </html>
```

## The Question

So, this above snippet transitions from start-to-end between the RGB colour values of `(0, 0, 0)` and `(240, 240, 240)` - regardless of the number of bars that is displayed.

Now, if I have two randomly generated objects which hold the data for two RGB colours, as so:

```
startColor = {
    r: floor(random(255)),
    g: floor(random(255)),
    b: floor(random(255))
}
endColor = {
    r: floor(random(255)),
    g: floor(random(255)),
    b: floor(random(255))
}
```

***How could I*** transition smoothly between these as the above snippet transitions between 0 and 240? I've been playing around and no code I run seems to produce a series of bars where the color of the first bar and the color of the end bar is even remotely similar to the true values of the `startColor` and `endColor` variables.

Thanks for reading. Please comment any questions below if this wasn't clear enough.

Comment: css transitions

Comment: @JaromandaX CSS is not part of JavaScript. Question is about JavaScript. CSS is not always available in environments where JavaScript can be running.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Lukas, for pointing me towards the original post with an answer that helped.

I've found a solution for all of you willing to use the P5.js library. First, define two RGB colors you'd like to transition between:

```
var startColor = color(
    floor(random(255)),
    floor(random(255)),
    floor(random(255))
);
var endColor = color(
    floor(random(255)),
    floor(random(255)),
    floor(random(255))
);
```

Next, define the color which transitions between the two:

```
var col = lerpColor(startColor, endColor, LEVEL);
```

`LEVEL` is a decimal ranging from 0 - 1, where 0 results in `col = startColor` and 1 results in `col = endColor`, and anything between transitions the two colours.

Apply `col` to a drawing through:

```
fill(col)
// draw rect, ellipse, etc...
```

And:

```
stroke(col)
// draw line
```

Read more on it [here](https://p5js.org/examples/color-lerp-color.html).